# How to display an input like x-editable?

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to make an editable manual with `ng-if` in AngularJS but when I click on one of the table cells, all the table cells in **Jumlah Pembelian** display the input form.

*before click*:

[image: image before click]

*after clicking on one cell*:

[image: after click one cell]

**My question**: how to display form input when I click one cell

My HTML code:

```
  <td ng-if="kons_makanan == 0" class="middle-vertical text-center" 
      ng-click="change_jumlah(bu.id)">{{jumlah_makanan}}</td>
  <td ng-if="kons_makanan == 1">
    <div class="form-inline">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" number-masking 
             ng-model="jumlah_makanan" style="width:auto;">
      <a class="btn btn-flat btn-sm btn-success"
         ng-click="update_jumlah_makanan(bu.id)" title="Tambah">
        <i class='fa fa-plus'></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </td>
```

My AngularJS code:

```
$scope.change_jumlah = function(no) {
    $scope.kons_makanan = 1;
}

$scope.update_jumlah_makanan = function(no) {
    $scope.kons_makanan = 0;
}
```

Comment: You're passing `bu.id` to the controller functions, so save the passed id inside `change_jumlah` (`$scope.kons_makanan = no;`) and in the `ngIf` directives check `ng-if="kons_makanan != bu.id"` (To show the value of the cell) and ``ng-if="kons_makanan == bu.id"`` (To show the input for updating the cell's value)

Comment: sorry still displaying all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone, I tried and was successful

HTML code:

```
<td ng-if="kons_makanan != $index" class="middle-vertical text-center" 
  ng-click="change_jumlah($index)">{{jumlah_makanan}}</td>

<td ng-if="kons_makanan == $index">
 <div class="form-inline">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" number-masking 
  ng-model="jumlah_makanan" style="width:auto;">
  <a class="btn btn-flat btn-sm btn-success"
     ng-click="update_jumlah_makanan(bu.id)" title="Tambah">
    <i class='fa fa-plus'></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

AngularJS code:

```
$scope.change_jumlah = function(no) {
   $scope.kons_makanan = no;
}

$scope.update_jumlah_makanan = function(no) {
   $scope.kons_makanan = -1;
}
```

Thanks all for trying to help me